# Search for string in file (line-by-line), ignoring the size of whitespace gaps between words

Tags: c++, string, file-io

I'm a beginner to C++, so please be understanding...

I want to search for a string (needle) within a file (haystack), by reading each line separately, then searching for the needle in that line. However, ideally for a more robust code I would like to be able to just read individual words on the line, so that if there are larger (i.e. multiple) white-space gaps betweeen words they are ignored when searching for the needle. (e.g perhaps using the >> operator??) That is, the needle string should not have to exactly match the size of the space between words in the file.

so for example, if I have a needle:

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

in the file this might be written (on a particular line) as:

```
... "The quick brown      fox jumps over the        lazy dog" ...
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Currently I include the necessary number of spaces in my needle string but I would like to improve the code, if possible.

My code currently looks something like the following (within a method in a class):

```
double var1, var2;
char skip[5];
std::fstream haystack ("filename");
std::string needle = "This is a string, and var1    =";
std::string line;
int pos;
bool found = false;

// Search for needle
while ( !found && getline (haystack,line) ) {
  pos = line.find(needle);  // find position of needle in current line

  if (pos != std::string::npos) { // current line contains needle

      std::stringstream lineStream(line);
      lineStream.seekg (pos + needle.length());
      lineStream >> var1;
      lineStream >> skip;
      lineStream >> var2;
      found = true;
  }
}
```

(Just for clarity, after finding the string (needle) I want to store the next word on that line or in some cases store the next word, then skip a word and store the following word, for example:

With a file:

```
... ...
... This is a string, and var1    = 111 and 777 ...
... ...
```

I want to extract `var1 = 111; var2 = 777;` )

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, although I think there's a shorter solution:

```
std::size_t myfind(std::string ins, std::string str) {
  for(std::string::iterator it = ins.begin(), mi = str.begin(); it != ins.end(); ++it) {
    if(*it == *mi) {
      ++mi;
      if (mi == str.end())
        return std::distance(ins.begin(),it);
    }
    else {
      if(*it == ' ')
        continue;
      mi = str.begin();
    }
  }
  return std::string::npos;
}
// use:
myfind("foo The quick brown      fox jumps over the        lazy dog bar", "The quick brown fox");
```

Comment: thanks for putting up working code! I assume this replaces the 'find' function, right? I'm not sure that I want to create a new function though, I'd rather include everything within my current code for now.

Comment: hmm I like this - but I believe this currently returns the length of the needle rather than the position within the haystack where the needle begins -which is what I wanted. I fixed it: `if (mi == str.begin())
              pos = it;
          ++mi;
          if (mi == str.end())
              return std::distance(ins.begin(),pos);
      }`

Comment: I tried changing this so that it instead returns the position in `ins` of the end of the `str` instead of the beginning but it doesn't work - why? - `if(*it == *mi) {
          ++mi;
          if (mi == str.end()) { pos = it;
              return std::distance(ins.begin(),pos); }
      }`

Comment: I realised why my code wasn't working - in order to achieve the same result as in my original code above, I need to add 1 to the distance returned, ie `return std::distance(ins.begin(),it+1);`

Answer (score 1):

You can find all sequences of white space characters in the `line` string, and replace them with a single white space. This way you would be able to replace multiple spaces in the `needle` as well, and the rest of your search algorithm would continue working unchanged.

Here is a way to remove duplicates using STL:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

struct DupSpaceDetector {
    bool wasSpace;
    DupSpaceDetector() : wasSpace(0) {}
    bool operator()(int c) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            if (wasSpace) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                wasSpace = 1;
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            wasSpace = 0;
            return 0;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    string source("The quick brown      fox jumps over the        lazy dog");
    string destination;
    DupSpaceDetector detector;
    remove_copy_if(
        source.begin()
    ,   source.end()
    ,   back_inserter(destination)
    ,   detector
    );
    cerr << destination << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response - so how would I implement that??

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you should strip extra spaces from the needle and the haystack line.  `std::unique` is defined to do this.  Normally it is used after sorting the range, but in this case all we really want to do is remove duplicate spaces.

```
struct dup_space
{
   bool operator()( char lhs, char rhs )
   {
      return std::isspace( lhs ) && std::isspace( rhs );
   }
};

void despacer( const std::string& in, std::string& out )
{
   out.reserve( in.size() );
   std::unique_copy( in.begin(), in.end(),
         std::back_insert_iterator( out ),
         dup_space()
      );
}
```

You should use it like this:

```
void find( const std::string& needle, std::istream haystack )
{
   std::string real_needle;
   despacer( needle, real_needle );

   std::string line;
   std::string real_line;
   while( haystack.good() )
   {
      line.clear();
      std::getline( haystack, line );

      real_line.clear();
      despacer( line, real_line );

      auto ret = real_line.find( real_needle );

      if( ret != std::string::npos )
      {
         // found it
         // do something creative
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: what does the `auto` do exactly? (Just by the way, I don't need to worry about removing spaces in the needle, that can be defined initially as a 'real_needle'.)

Comment: oops some c++11 slipped in.  `auto` just tells the compiler to put the right type in its place while compiling.  In this case it would be `std::string::size_type`.